# My .minecraft folder doesn`t have a saves folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I installed Minecraft, I cannot find the "saves" folder in '`.minecraft`'?
What is going on and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any saves?

Comment: Like @Kevin said, if you haven't created any world there will not be a `saves` folder with a clean nstall of MC.

Answer (score 3):

Run your game and start a new one. The save folder will be created with your first save

Comment: This. Also, you could manually create it using your operating system's file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Like they said, starting the game and making a new world will make it. But...

But if you changed your profile's directory in the launcher (third-party launchers like the Curse client, FTB launcher, Technic launcher, etc, will do it automatically for each saved instance / modpack you have), you can still find where it saved. If it ever starts the vanilla-looking before-playing screen, select the correct profile via. the drop-down menu in the bottom left of the window, then click the "Edit Profile" button near it. If the profile overrides the save location, it will show a checkbox that is ticked/selected and the path to it on its right in a textbox. This location is quickly accessible by clicking on the button at the bottom of this window that would open where it saves the profile's data to.

Comment: I don't think they've used any third party launchers/custom profiles because they have a fresh install of minecraft

Answer (score -1):

Just go into the .minecraft folder, make a new folder. Call it saves. Done.